# Is it possible to compile potrace for iOS?

Tags: ios, compilation, vector-graphics, potrace

Looking at the cross-platform nature of potrace http://potrace.sourceforge.net/, is it possible to compile this for iOS? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to compile **potrace** for iOS.

As a matter of fact, most open source libraries using standard (GNU) configure tools that compile on MacOS X will easily compile on iOS, because they are likely free of platform-specific code (e.g. *linuxisms*) and standard configure tools allow cross-compilation.

You can compile these libraries in the shell by pointing configure to the proper toolchain and SDKs. Paths changed with Mavericks and Xcode 5, but fortunately automated scripts exist for more popular libraries such as expat.

The proposed solution is based on the [x2on/expat-ios](https://github.com/x2on/expat-ios) project on GitHub. Their script *fixes* expat's `config.sub` which doesn't know about arm64 target. Do does potrace 1.11's `config.sub`. However, a simpler approach consists in downloading a more recent version of `config.sub`. Unlike expat, potrace doesn't seem to need any patch to compile for iOS.

Full script `build-potrace.sh` is available here:
https://gist.github.com/pguyot/dce18af64a71b93c0204

Please note that potrace is licensed under the GPLv2. You might want to check [Is it legal to publish iOS apps under the GNU GPLv3 open-source license?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762498/iphone-and-gpl) question.

Comment: Absolutely what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: A non-GPL version of Potrace is available according to Potrace website: http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#license.

"A non-GPL version of Potrace, called Potrace Professional(TM), is available for integration into proprietary software."