# Extract bezier paths from a png

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I want to extract bezier paths from a png like this.
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8uWK.png)

Comment: What do you want to do with the beside paths once you've extracted them?

Comment: I want to color it. color separate elements in deferent colors. Thats why I want bezier paths of separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

potrace doesn't support reading PNG files natively. You'd need to convert PNG images to another supported format first. http://potrace.sourceforge.net/faq.html#formats

However potrace is licensed under the GPL so while it does compile for iOS you may not want to use it as part of an app. [Is it possible to compile potrace for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702706/35794) There is a non-GPL version of potrace available, but it isn't free.

Depending on the complexity of the PNG images you want to convert, you may get less than ideal results anyway.

If you update your question with more detail about what you are trying to achieve it might be possible to give a better answer.