# How do you install the Potrace command line tool?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, potrace

The [instructions](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/INSTALL) make no sense to me. I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it, cd in the directory, and `./configure` is not found.

Comment: So my first try will be you could come out of the installation directory and try to search it with `find` command eg--> `find -type f -iname "configure"` once you find it then you are good to run it, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to compile potrace for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702706/is-it-possible-to-compile-potrace-for-ios)